# Amazon SQS FIFO Queue sending message failed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo, signing

We are trying to send a message to AWS FIFO queue. We already have a working version of the code which sends the message to SQS standard queue.

Python code (Our requirement is not to use SDK):[Examples of the Complete Version 4 Signing Process (Python)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html?shortFooter=true)

For the standard queue, we used following params

```
    method = 'GET'
    service = 'sqs'
    host = 'sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
    region = 'us-west-2'
    endpoint = 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx/TestQueue'
    request_parameters = 'Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=mytest&Version=2012-11-05'
    canonical_uri = '/xxxxxx/TestQueue'
```

For the FIFO Queue, we used the same code and additionally modified as follows

```
method = 'GET'
service = 'sqs'
host = 'sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-west-2'
endpoint = 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/Test.fifo'
request_parameters = 'Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=mytest&MessageGroupId=test&MessageDeduplicationId=ttte&Version=2012-11-05'
canonical_uri = '/xxxxxxx/Test.fifo'
```

But it is failed. Are we missing anything, can anyone help us?

```
Response code: 403

<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it's a good, clear, answerable question with attempt and expected vs observed behavior. Answer just happens to be buried in the documentation.  Wish I saw more questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing algorithm requires that you sort your parameters lexically before signing.  This is part of why the term *canonical* is used in describing the "canonical query string."  They don't necessarily need to be sent to the server, sorted, in the actual request, but they do have to be sorted for signing to produce the correct result.

`MessageGroupId` needs to be after `MessageDeduplicationId`, not before.

This is mentioned in the code example on the page you linked to:

```
# Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
# request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
# be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
# For this example, the query string is pre-formatted in the request_parameters variable.
```

A better implementation than this simplified example might take the parameters as a dictionary, and sort it, to build the canonical query string.  A better implementation might also handle url-escaping of the keys and values automatically.